# Size of speed brakes for glider

Tags: aerodynamics, glider, glide-ratio, model-aircraft, airbrakes

I have a concept glider and I am trying to calculate the required speed brake area. The clean glide ratio is currently 30, and with speedbrakes, I am aiming at reducing it to something around 7.

I know that the Cd of the speedbrakes is around 1.5.
As for other specs, the wing area is 12 square meters, the AR is 18 and the glider weighs 400 kilos clean.

How can I calculate it?

Comment: Take the Cd  of the glider clean, then work the speed brake drag based on its area.  Glide ratio  × weight gives you your needed total drag.

Comment: Most modern gliders, as a safety feature, have "speed limiting brakes", which means if you pull them all the way out the glider can't exceed Vne in any attitude. Your target drag should be sufficient to keep the glider from exceeding Vne in a vertical dive.